# Prove that $D_{5}$ is not nilpotent

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, propositional-calculus

**I am trying to show that the dihedral group of $10$ elements, $D_{5}$ is not nilpotent** Now, I know of a result that says the center of $D_{n} = Z(D_{n}) = \{ e\}$ when $n$ is odd, but I suppose that I need to prove that for any group $G$, $Z(G)=\{e\} \, \implies \, G$ is not nilpotent.

I came across a result that says that if $G$ is a nilpotent group with $|G|>1$, then $|Z(G)|>1$. I **think** that the contrapositive of this statement is that if $|Z(G)|=1$, then $G$ is either not nilpotent, or $|G|=1$. Is this the correct contraposition? If so, then I believe this result is exactly what I am looking for. However, sometimes I get logical negation wrong, which is why I'm asking.

If this is not true, or if this is not how one shows that $D_{5}$ is not nilpotent, could you please tell me and let me know how I should show it?

Thanks.

Comment: You are right about what the contrapositive is. (It would be a very good plan to read up a bit on that so as to get more confidence with such things: it will certainly be more and more difficult to continue with group theory —or anything really— without it!)

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez thank you! This means I can prove it the way I wanted to prove it!

Answer (score 1):

A nilpotent group is the direct product of its Sylow subgroups. Show that your group is not.

Comment: we haven't learned about Sylow subgroups yet. So, this approach to the problem is no good to me.

Comment: Well, eventually you will learn about Sylow subgroups. There is no hurry for this answer to be good to you!